# Download file from MINIO with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, minio

New in node.js! please ignore incase invalid question!
I am having one minio bucket hosted in local server. I wanted to download data from minio bucket to user machine with help to following flow:

Valid user on browser => Node.js backend (To validate minio access) => Minio.

Following are two concern:

- I tried to execute my minio download commands on Node.js backend but its downloading on backend only not on user machine. How to download data on user machine?
- Size of my download file might be very big which might not be handled by Node.js backend due to size restriction on backend. hence how to download data on user machine with small small chunk?

Any example will be really appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches to choose from, but I will give you the approach that I think is best. (Only my opinion, not a fact).

With a presigned URL, you can generate a URL with an expiration time, and the user's browser can use that URL to download the file directly from Minio, bypassing the need to go through your Node.js backend during the download process.

In this approach, Your Node.js backend receives the request from the user and validates their access to the Minio object. Upon successful validation, the backend generates a presigned URL for the specific Minio object, setting an expiration time as needed.The backend sends the presigned URL back to the user's browser. The user's browser uses the presigned URL to download the file directly from Minio.

You can generate a presigned URL in your Node.js backend using the Minio SDK. Implementation will be something like this,

```
const minioClient = new Minio.Client({
  endPoint: 'your-minio-endpoint',
  port: 9000,
  useSSL: false,
  accessKey: 'your-minio-access-key',
  secretKey: 'your-minio-secret-key',
})

app.get('/presigned-download/:objectKey', async (req, res) => {
  const objectKey = req.params.objectKey
  const bucketName = 'your-bucket-name'
  const expiration = 60 * 5 // URL valid for 5 minutes (adjust as needed)

  try {
    // Validate user access here

    // Generate a presigned URL for the Minio object
    const presignedUrl = await minioClient.presignedGetObject(bucketName, objectKey, expiration);

    // Send the presigned URL back to the user
    res.send({ url: presignedUrl })
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error generating presigned URL:', err)
    res.status(500).send('Error generating presigned URL')
  }
```

Then on the frontend, user can initiate the download using the received presigned URL. You can read further on this topic [here](https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/javascript/API.html#presignedurl-httpmethod-bucketname-objectname-expiry-reqparams-requestdate-cb)